# The edits to Rails models, generated in Docker, do not update in Docker when migrating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, rails-migrations

I am trying to generate a migration, for which I first enter with

```
docker compose exec rails bash.
```

Then I create the migration using

```
rails generate model
```

and it is successfully created locally. After that, I edit this migration in VSCode. However, when I run

```
rails db:migrate
```

the migration is created as if it were generated with 'rails generate,' without taking into account the edits.

If I bring up the containers again, perform a rollback, and migrate again, the error persists.

How can I ensure that the Docker environment executes the edits to the migration file so that it migrates correctly?